# signInWithCredential returns error in auth flow for Chrome extension (manifest v3)

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to authenticate a user in the background script (service worker) of a Chrome extension (manifest v3) with Firebase. I'm using the `signInWithCredential` method and passing an idToken (info below), but this returns the following error:

```
error: id token is not issued by Google. (auth/invalid-credential).
```

My auth flow is this:

1. user clicks "sign in" button in the popup of the Chrome extension.
2. Chrome extension opens a new Tab and redirects to my web app (online) where the user can log in to their account via Firebase (either via Google OAuth or email/password combination).
3. Once the user is authenticated on the website, this generates an idToken from the client with `currenUser.getIdToken()`. Like so:

```js
auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {
    // saves the token to be used later
    return idToken
})
```

4. The website then sends the resulting idToken to the chrome extension with `window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...)`.
5. The Chrome extension receives the idToken (all good until here) and tries to log in with `signInWithCredential`. Here it displays the error mentioned above.

A few more notes:

1. I checked that the chrome extension and the hosted webpage are connected to the same project in Firebase.
2. I need to authenticate users that have previously signed up either with Google OAuth or email/password combination, therefore I cannot use the `chrome.identity` API that has been mentioned elsewhere.

Any pointers on how to solve this?

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just working on this today. I found two things that worked for me, not sure if they are the simplest solutions, but they work:

1. Rather than using getIdToken in step 3, once the user is authenticated, call a cloud function that generates a token using createCustomToken, then immediately pass it back to the client and forward it on to the extension. Here's more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
2. The auth emulator rejects the token but if you deploy the cloud function then it works.

Let me know if you'd like any more specifics. Again, I don't love this solution because you then have to keep sending the extension messages when the auth changes on the website. But until someone's got a better idea, it's all I could find/work out.